# Error with Switching frames in Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying out a python GUI as part of the school curriculum, I am trying to switch frames using a button, that is set to destroy the old frame and open the new one, while I am not having any trouble opening a new frame I cannot seem to destroy the old one or load any widgets etc. into the new frame. Here is the part of the code I am having trouble with:

```
class welcomePage(tk.Frame):

def __init__(self, parent, controller):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
    self.controller = controller

    homebutton = tk.Button(self, text = "Return Home", command=lambda: self.home(), width = 30, height = 1)
    homebutton.pack(padx = 10, pady= 20 )

    cswitch = tk.Button(self, text = "Customer Interface", command=lambda: (self.destroy, CustomerPage()), width = 30, height = 1)
    cswitch.pack(padx = 10, pady= 15 )

    exit = tk.Button(self, text="Exit", command=self.destroy, width = 30, height = 1)
    exit.pack(padx = 10, pady= 20 )

class CustomerPage(tk.Tk):
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)


    self.title("Customer Interface")
    self.minsize(width = 300, height = 100)
    self.maxsize(width = 9999, height = 9999)
    tab_control = tk.Notebook(self)
    admin1 = tk.Frame(tab_control)
    admin2 = tk.Frame(tab_control)
    admin3 = tk.Frame(tab_control)
    admin4 = tk.Frame(tab_control)
    tab_control.add(admin1, text='Menu')
    tab_control.add(admin2, text='DataBase')
    tab_control.add(admin3, text='Sales History')
    tab_control.add(admin4, text='Search')        

                # -- Menu -- #

    homebutton = tk.Button(admin1, text = "Return Home", command=lambda: self.home(), width = 30, height = 1)
    homebutton.pack(padx = 10, pady= 30 )

    cswitch = tk.Button(admin1, text = "Admin Interface", command=lambda: self.cswitch(), width = 30, height = 1)
    cswitch.pack(padx = 10, pady= 10 )

    exit = tk.Button(admin1, text="Exit", command=self.destroy, width = 30, height = 1)
    exit.pack(padx = 10, pady= 30 )
```

Here is the error I am getting: AttributeError: module 'tkinter' has no attribute 'Notebook'

I cant find anything online regarding this specific error so any help is greatly appreciated :).

Comment: I think you're looking for `ttk.Notebook`. (`import tkinter.ttk as ttk`)

Comment: @Aran-Fey that gives me this error: AttributeError: type object 'Notebook' has no attribute 'tk'  - I tried changing all of the tk.Frames to ttk.Frame aswell but the error stayed the same.

Comment: Please create a [mcve]. Your code is very confusing. One "page" is the root window and one "page" is a frame. It's not clear if that's intentional or not. Plus, you're not creating instance of either of those classes.  Allso, as Aran-Fey mentioned, the error is correct: tkinter doesn't have a Notebook. You need to use the Notebook from the ttk package. And finally, please fix the indentation problems in your code.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
from tkinter import ttk

tab_control = ttk.Notebook(self)
```